# Eclipse-PDE: funny IDE behaviour when extending AbstractDecoratedTextEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm programming Eclipse plugins using Kepler SR2. Let's say I create a blank plugin `plugin1`,  and add the following dummy class:

```
package com.example.plugin1;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor;

public class MyEditor extends AbstractDecoratedTextEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEditor.class);
    }
}
```

The IDE doesn't give me the natural fix hint (add `org.eclipse.ui.editors`), I add it manually to the dependencies ("Required Plug-ins"). Then funny things start to happen.
The class still is marked as having errors, and the following cryptic error appears:

> The type org.eclipse.jface.text.revisions.RevisionInformation cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I'm not sure what this means, so I try adding `org.eclipse.jface.text` to the required plugins. Then it compiles without errors. But when I try to execute my (admitedly stupid, but legal) class from the Eclipse launcher, and a strange popup from the Launcher: "A Java exception has occurred", and the console spits this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/actions/WorkspaceModifyOperation
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I also tried to load the class in runtime by using `Class.forName` (in another class)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("trying...");
    Class c=Class.forName("com.example.plugin1.MyEditor");
    System.out.println("class=" + c);
}
```

and it fails again when loading the class. If I launch that in Debug mode, I can check that Eclipse launcher seems to compute rightly the classpath: here's my dump:

```
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui_3.105.0.v20130522-1122.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.swt_3.102.1.v20140206-1334.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.102.1.v20140206-1358.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface_3.9.1.v20130725-1141.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.2.v20140211-1711.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3_0.12.0.v20130515-1857.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.100.v20131218-1515.jar
\eclipse\plugins\javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201209060031.jar
\eclipse\plugins\javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.300.v20130429-1813.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.200.v20130514-1256\runtime_registry_compatibility.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.100.v20130422-1538.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20130326-1255.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20130327-1442.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.8.100.v20130513-1637.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_3.5.300.v20130225-1821.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.101.v20130802-1147.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.text_3.5.300.v20130515-1451.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.9.2.v20131004-0923.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.views_3.6.100.v20130326-1250.jar
\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.8.101.v20130729-1318.jar
```

I cannot make sense of this. Why cannot I load the class? Any idea?

Comment: You can't run Eclipse plugins from your own `main` like this, you must use `Run As > Eclipse Application` so that the correct Eclipse `main` method is used. Eclipse has a lot of initialization that must be done to make the plugin system function correctly.

Comment: I know, I have my Eclipse-RCP already working, but the problem here is not in instantiating/running the classes inside the OSGI environment, but just attempting to do a simple class loading from the outside, from some tooling app. Classes for a Eclipse plugin should be usable (perhaps partially, at least loadable) from a headless caller, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed it by adding some more plugins. The full set of needed plugins, in addition to  `org.eclipse.ui.editors` seems to be:

```
org.eclipse.jface.text
org.eclipse.ui
org.eclipse.core.resources
org.eclipse.core.filesystem
```

These is merely empirical. I wonder why I had to add these manually, shouldn't they be required dependencies from `org.eclipse.ui.editors`?...

Comment: Some plugins dependencies can be marked as `re export` and won't be added to the explicit dependencies of other plugins.